# USB drive won't mount

Tags: usb

I'm having a problem with a USB thumb drive that I used to be able to read and write to with no issues. On two different Macs: MacBook Pro and iMac, it doesn't mount. It doesn't even show up in DiskUtility. The only thing that happens when it gets plugged in is that `dmesg` shows the line `USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 0x58f 0x1234 0x1`. I checked System Profiler and it showed the following for the device:

```
Mass Storage Device:

  Product ID:   0x1234
  Vendor ID:    0x058f  (Alcor Micro, Corp.)
  Version:   0.01
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Alcor Micro
  Location ID:  0xfa200000 / 2
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    100
```

Which to me looks like everything's good. Through some googleing I found out about USB Prober. Someone said that after running USB Prober their drive showed up. I ran the tool, but my drive didn't appear, and it showed this output for my device:

```
High Speed device @ 2 (0xFA200000): .............................................   Composite device: "Mass Storage Device"
    Port Information:   0x001a
           Not Captive
           Attached to Root Hub
           External Device
           Connected
           Enabled
    Device Descriptor   
        Descriptor Version Number:   0x0200
        Device Class:   0   (Composite)
        Device Subclass:   0
        Device Protocol:   0
        Device MaxPacketSize:   64
        Device VendorID/ProductID:   0x058F/0x1234   (Alcor Micro, Inc.)
        Device Version Number:   0x0001
        Number of Configurations:   1
        Manufacturer String:   1 "Alcor Micro"
        Product String:   2 "Mass Storage Device"
        Serial Number String:   0 (none)
    Configuration Descriptor   
        Length (and contents):   32
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0000: 09 02 20 00 01 01 00 80  32 09 04 00 00 02 08 06  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0010: 50 00 07 05 01 02 00 02  00 07 05 82 02 00 02 00  
            Unknown Descriptor   0020: 
        Number of Interfaces:   1
        Configuration Value:   1
        Attributes:   0x80 (bus-powered)
        MaxPower:   100 ma
        Interface #0 - Mass Storage/SCSI   
            Alternate Setting   0
            Number of Endpoints   2
            Interface Class:   8   (Mass Storage)
            Interface Subclass;   6   (SCSI)
            Interface Protocol:   80
            Endpoint 0x01 - Bulk Output   
                Address:   0x01  (OUT)
                Attributes:   0x02  (Bulk no synchronization data endpoint)
                Max Packet Size:   512
                Polling Interval:   0 ( Endpoint never NAKs)
            Endpoint 0x82 - Bulk Input   
                Address:   0x82  (IN)
                Attributes:   0x02  (Bulk no synchronization data endpoint)
                Max Packet Size:   512
                Polling Interval:   0 ( Endpoint never NAKs)
    Device Qualifier Descriptor   
        Descriptor Version Number:   0x0200
        Device Class   0   (Composite)
        Device Subclass   0
        Device Protocol   0
        Device MaxPacketSize:   64
        Number of Configurations:   1
        bReserved:   0
    Other Speed Configuration Descriptor   
        Length (and contents):   32
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0000: 09 07 20 00 01 01 00 80  32 09 04 00 00 02 08 06  
            Raw Descriptor (hex)    0010: 50 00 07 05 01 02 40 00  00 07 05 82 02 40 00 00  
            Unknown Descriptor   0020: 
        Number of Interfaces:   1
        Configuration Value:   1
        Attributes:   0x80 (bus-powered)
        MaxPower:   100 ma
        Interface #0 - Mass Storage/SCSI   
            Alternate Setting   0
            Number of Endpoints   2
            Interface Class:   8   (Mass Storage)
            Interface Subclass;   6   (SCSI)
            Interface Protocol:   80
            Endpoint 0x01 - Bulk Output   
                Address:   0x01  (OUT)
                Attributes:   0x02  (Bulk no synchronization data endpoint)
                Max Packet Size:   64
                Polling Interval:   0 ms
            Endpoint 0x82 - Bulk Input   
                Address:   0x82  (IN)
                Attributes:   0x02  (Bulk no synchronization data endpoint)
                Max Packet Size:   64
                Polling Interval:   0 ms
```

Everything looks like it's all set for a USB drive, I don't understand why it's not mounting.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution found. Don't even remember what happened to that drive.